# Vite Serving Libraries without CDN

Tags: bootstrap-5, vite, cdn, content-delivery-network

We know that vanilla HTML+CSS+JS uses a CDN (Content Delivery Network) approach a lot. Bootstrap, as an example, can be served with jsDeliver. Does that mean I'll lose the increase in performance and reliability of CDNs when I use vite?

Say I'm developing a project with Vite and Bootstrap CSS. If I `npm install bootstrap`, the CSS & JS files go to my local `node_modules/`. Unless I'm mistaken, that means bootstrap is served by my server in production time (after my project is built).

Comment: Vite uses Rollup as a module bundler. When you install packages through npm, they get included in the build output files (assuming they're not dev dependencies). That output bundle is included in the HTML via a <script> tag that gets hosted on your server and executed on the client-side.  It's not necessary to use a CDN, but if you want to you can use services like jsDeliver or Unpkg to serve your files. You may need to publish your code to NPM or GitHub to use these services though.